# How do you format rendered yaml arrays in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

Can you help me solve this problem? I've not managed to find any documentation on this, no doubt because it's such a simple thing that no one's thought to write it down!

I'm debugging some oauth functionality in a Rails app, and needing to regularly refer to the access token, which I'm rendering as text to_yaml.

`render :text => request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml`

Is there a quick way to format the response? I currently have one long array displayed in my browser, which makes reading very challenging!

Can I get each item to display on a separate line, ideally nested under parent items?

For example, currently I have this: `--- provider: twitter uid: '#####' info: nickname: username name: User Name` and I want this:

```
--- 
provider: twitter 
uid: '#####' 
info: 
    nickname: username 
    name: User Name
```

I'm sure I'm overlooking something very obvious. Appreciate if someone can point it out to me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the magic `pre` tag:

```
<pre><%= @foo.to_yaml %></pre>
```

EDIT: Better fit for your example:

```
render :text => "<pre>#{request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml}</pre>" # quick and dirty
```

If you use this a lot, refactor it into a helper method somewhere.

Comment: 'faceplant' I knew I was being slow! Thanks Thilo, saved me! Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

The most concise way:

```
<%= debug @foo %>
```

It styles `pre` tag with `debug_dump` class.